# Vectors: $a = (1,2)$, $ b= (2,-1)$, $c = (-5, 20)$ Find values for $k$ and $l$ for $c = la + kb$

Tags: vector-spaces

We have these vectors: $a = (1,2)$, $ b= (2,-1)$, $c = (-5, 20)$

and I have to find values for  $k$ and $l$ given this:  $c = la + kb$

How do I go on about solving this one? Do I have to calculate the distances of these vectors or use the multiplying formula? I'm a bit puzzled right here, I've forgotten all about vectors and have a hard time remembering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$(-5,20)=l(1,2)+k(2,-1)$$

$$\implies l+2k=-5,-k+2l= 20$$

Can you solve the two linear simultaneous equations for the two unknowns namey, $k,l$?

Comment: Oh so that's how you do it, thanks! Got the results correct; $l = 7, k= -6$

Answer (score 2):

$la+kb=(l,2l)+(2k,-k)=(l+2k,2l-k)$, and this must be equal to $(-5,20)$.